# Old style numeral labels and body text

Tags: biblatex, citing, oldstylenums

Here's what I want to achieve with `biblatex`:

1. The label and in the text, the year (four digits) in old style figures and everything in `\small`
2. Prenote (see ~), if any, in `\small`
3. Post Note, if any, the abbreviation p in `\small`, the page number in old style figures and also in `\small`

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{alexander:1964,
Author               = {C. Alexander},
Title                  = {{Notes on the Syntheses of Form}},
Publisher            = {Harverd University Press},
Year                  = {1964},
Address               = {Cambridge Massachusetts London},
Edition               = {7},
Series               = {},
Keywords            = {Literatur},
Label                  = {\textsc{\small{Alexander}} 19}}

@Manual{din66253:1989,
Title                = {{{\small\textsc{\itshape DIN}~66\,253-3:} Programmiersprache {\small\textsc{\itshape PEARL}}~--~Teil 3: {\small Mehr\-rechner-\textsc{\itshape PEARL}}}},
Organization      = {Deutsches Institut f{\"u}r Normung},
Year                   = {1989},
Keywords            = {Normen},
Label                  = {{\small\textsc{DIN}~66\,253-3} 19}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
        style=alphabetic, 
        natbib=true, 
        sorting=anyt, 
        maxbibnames=10, 
        maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\citep[][S.~1234]{alexander:1964}, \citep[][]{din66253:1989}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Hi there,
in the meantime I was able to find a solution to my problem. it is
determines everything much easier, but the "depths" of biblatex are me so far
remained hidden.
Biblatex reacts very accurately in terms of sorting the label. therefore
these must be distinguished consistently. This is not observed, it is
at least with the solution found by me to sort incorrect.
Here is my solution:

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@Book{alexander:1964, 
Author               = {C. Alexander}, 
Title                  = {{Notes on the Syntheses of Form}}, 
Publisher            = {Harverd University Press}, 
Year                  = {1964}, 
Address               = {Cambridge Massachusetts London}, 
Edition               = {7}, 
Series               = {}, 
Keywords            = {Literatur}, 
Label                  = {\textsc{\small{Alexander}} {\small\oldstylenums{1964}}} 
} 
@Manual{din66253:1989, 
Title                = {{{\small\textsc{\itshape DIN}~66\,253-3:} Programmiersprache {\small\textsc{\itshape PEARL}}~--~Teil 3: {\small Mehr\-rechner-\textsc{\itshape PEARL}}}}, 
Organization      = {Deutsches Institut f{\"u}r Normung}, 
Year                   = {1989}, 
Keywords            = {Normen}, 
Label                  = {{\small\textsc{DIN}~66\,253-3} {\small\oldstylenums{1989}}} 
}
@Book{alexander:1977,
Author                  = {C. Alexander and S. Ishikawa and M. Silverstein and M. Jacobsen and I. Fiksdahl-King and S. Angel},
Title                       = {{A Pattern Language: Towns~--~Buildings~--~Construction}},
Publisher               = {Oxford University Press},
Year                        = {1977},
Address                 = {New York},
Edition                 = {},
Series                  = {},
Keywords                = {Literatur},
Label                       = {{\small\textsc{Alexander}} {\small\textsc{et al.}} {\small\oldstylenums{1977}}}
}
@Article{nuettgens:2002, 
Author                  = {M. N{\"u}ttgens and F.~J. Rump},
Title                   = {{Syntax und Semantik Ereignisgesteuerter Prozessketten {\small (\textsc{EPK})}}}, 
Journal                 = {Prozessorientierte Methoden und Werkzeuge für die Entwicklung von Informationssystemen (Promise).}, 
Year                        = {2002},
Volume                  = {},
Number                  = {},
Pages                   = {64--77},
Keywords                = {Literatur},
Label                       = {{\small\textsc{N{\"u}ttgens}} {\small\&} {\small\textsc{Rump}} {\small\oldstylenums{2002}}}  
} 
\end{filecontents} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    natbib=true,
    sorting=nyt,
    maxbibnames=10,
    maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{%
  \labelelement{%
    \field{label}
  }
} 
\begin{document}
\citep[vgl.~][S.~1234]{alexander:1964}\par\citep{din66253:1989}\par\citep[vgl.~][S.~100--103]{alexander:1977}\par\citep[vgl.~][S.~4711]{nuettgens:2002}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that one normally should not have to set the label manually, what you do here reminds me of what `biblatex` does by default in the `authoryear` style. I also find all the formatting commands in the label and title quite particular. Did you find a way to make post and prenotes `\small`?